# Bits into char array

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I need to transfrom bits into char array or string, help to find best way to store bits and what shoud I do if for example I have 18 bits I will make 2 char and 2 bits?

Comment: Needs more details. What do you want to do exactly with those bits? Do you want to write them as a string?

Comment: A .NET char is 16 bit, you might be more interested in bytes

Comment: briffly i'm trying to save bit's into file but as far as i understand i only can save byte so i'm trying to get char from bit's and save them!

Comment: Is this C# question? I smell C++ background here. :)

Comment: unfortunately i need to work with bit's in C#=)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to store bits in C# is in the BitArray class, if you just need them as bits. If you need the integer value of the 18 bits, then you have to convert them to int or double or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

First step would be to convert your bit array into bytes and once you have an array of bytes you will need to choose a proper encoding and convert to a string which is an array of chars:

```
BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(new[] { true, false, true, false, });
byte[] bytes = new byte[bitArray.Length];
bitArray.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
char[] result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes).ToCharArray();
```

Obviously you need to know the encoding of those bits in order to be able to convert to characters. If you don't know the encoding you should reconsider what you are trying to do.